# Why is there an emf induced across the width of a metal sheet when it is moved across a uniform magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electrons, voltage, electromagnetic-induction

[image]By Faraday's law, the flux is constant, so there will be no emf. But each electron in the metal sheet is moved at some speed, so it will experience a force, and as a result, electrons will accumulate at the edges of the metal sheet ( basically, the hall effect ). I've asked a similar question before, and it involved me incorrectly applying Faraday's law; is that also the case here?

Comment: Search term: "motional emf".

Comment: I'm aware that an emf will be induced but does this not violate Faraday's law?

Comment: Faraday's law requires that you compute around the closed edge of a surface element through which you compute the flux. As long as your whole loop is inside the field, those loops will give zero EMF: $+\mathcal{E}$ as you go one way across the sheet plus $-\mathcal{E}$ as you go the other way...

Comment: So you agree that Faraday's law predicts zero emf? And I'm assuming the entire sheet is inside the field, so all the loops are as well.

Comment: Faraday's law predicts zero net EMF *for a full trip around the path*. That does not preclude there being a difference between the ends of the sheet, because a full trip *must* go as much back as it goes forward so that it ends where it starts.

Comment: What if we consider a loop which includes both ends of the sheet?

Comment: **those loops will give zero EMF: $+\mathcal{E}$ as you go one way across the sheet plus $-\mathcal{E}$ as you go the other way...**

Comment: I've added a picture to clarify the loop I'm thinking about. The curved section is directed out of the plane of the page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58484/discussion-between-dmckee-and-saad).

Answer (score 1):

As dmckee points out in the comments, Faraday's law essentially states that the line integral of the electric field *along a closed path* is proportional to the rate of change of magnetic flux *through a surface bounded by the closed path*.  This line integral gives the *emf* associated with the loop.

Since the flux through a surface bounded by the path you've drawn has constant magnetic flux through (by stipulation), the emf as defined above, is zero.

If you were to connect a conductor to the edges of the plates along the path you've drawn, there would be no (steady) current since there is no emf.

The reason is that the Lorentz force on the electrons in the attached conductor are driven in the opposite sense around the loop as the electrons in the plate.

In this scenario, to get an emf and thus drive charge along a closed conductive path, you must arrange things such that the magnetic flux threading the conductive path changes with time.

One way to do this is let the plate rest on conductive rails that are connected to a load at their ends like so:

[image]

[Image credit](http://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/induced-emf-two-circuits-contain-emf-produced-moving-metal-rod-likethat-shown-drawing-spee-q697822)

Comment: If there is no emf associated with my loop, why does adding a voltmeter produce a reading?

Comment: @Saad, you haven't completely specified your question.  Ordinarily, of one connects the leads of a voltmeter together, the measured voltage is zero.  However, if a changing magnetic flux threads the loop formed by the connected leads, there *will* be a reading.  So you must specify how the voltmeter is connected.  If the voltmeter is connected across the plate and moves with the plate, I don't believe there will be a reading for the same reason there would be nor current were it an ammeter you connected across the plate.